# If $\bf a$ is a constant vector field, and $\bf r$ is the position vector, prove that: $\nabla (\bf a\cdot \bf r)=\bf a$

Tags: vector-analysis

If $\bf a$ is a constant vectorial field (constant magnitude and direction), and $\bf r$ is the position vector, prove that:

$$\nabla (\mathbf a \cdot \bf r)=\mathbf a $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by $ar$ the OP means $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r$, where $\mathbf r$ is the position vector.  Then with $\mathbf a = (a_x, a_y, a_z)^T$ and $\mathbf r = (x, y, z)^T$, we have

$\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r = a_x x + a_y y + a_z z; \tag{1}$

and since

$\nabla (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r) = (\dfrac{\partial \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r}{\partial x}, \dfrac{\partial \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r}{\partial y}, \dfrac{\partial \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r}{\partial z})^T, \tag{2}$

we merely need observe that

$\dfrac{\partial \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial (a_x x + a_y y + a_z z)}{\partial x} = a_x, \tag{3}$

with the analogous results holding for partial differentiation with respect to $y$ and $z$.  Thus

$\nabla (\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r) = (a_x, a_y, a_z)^T, \tag{4}$

as was to be shown.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: oh, i see, and $\dfrac{\partial \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial (a_x x + a_y y + a_z z)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial (a_x x)}{\partial x}= \dfrac{\partial (a_x)}{\partial x}\cdot x+ a_x\cdot\dfrac{\partial (x)}{\partial x}$

And since a is constant, implies $\dfrac{\partial (a_x)}{\partial x}=0$, am i right?
So, we get that:

$\dfrac{\partial \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf r}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial (a_x)}{\partial x}\cdot x+ a_x\cdot\dfrac{\partial (x)}{\partial x}=a_x$

Comment: @Victor Francisco Salazar:  that's the long way, every step written out, but sure, you got it!

Comment: Yes, but im just trying to understand why it happens, tank you very much¡

Comment: And by Fiat Lux I suppose you mean the Maxwell equations? :)

Comment: @Victor Francisco Salazar:  hey, nothing wrong with the long way; seeing every step helps!  I do it myself *all the time*!

Comment: @orion:  yeah, those and a million other things!